# Spring Boot best practicies for static factory initializations of non-bean objects in service-class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I would like to refactor an application where some fields are initialized with static factory methods. It makes unit testing difficult and these fields can only be set via reflection in unit tests.
Here is one code example I would like to refactor

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor 
public class MyService {
   private final RemoteService remoteService = RemoteServiceFactory.newInstance();

   private final MySecondService secondService;

   .... 

}
```

As you can see there is a field which is initialized via factory. Autowiring is not possible because no beans of this type are found. RemoteService is legacy code from maven dependency.

I'm searching for some solution for dependency injection because you cannot really test my service properly without reflection.

What are best practicies to avoid such initialization in service classes?

Comment: Why don't you just make `RemoteService` a bean and let spring autowire it?

Comment: I don't understand why standard constructor injection wouldn't work here. If there is a reason, please update the question and explain why normal autowiring doesn't cover your use case.

Comment: @Chaosfire do you mean a wrapper over this legacy initialization so I can inject it? RemoteService isn't a bean

Comment: No need for a wrapper, declare it using `@Bean`. Edit - there is already an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77172421/17795888) showing exactly what i meant.

Comment: @Jorn I've updated my question. My problem is that RemoteService is a legacy implemention which is not a bean and couldn't been autowired. I'm looking for best practies for such cases whith such legacy implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1** : Define RemoteService as a Bean so you can create a Java Config class (annotated with @Configuration) to define RemoteService as a Spring bean.

```
@Configuration
public class RemoteServiceConfig {

   @Bean
    public RemoteService remoteService() {
    return RemoteServiceFactory.newInstance();
   }
}
```

**Step 2** :  Inject RemoteService through Constructor

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyService {
   private final RemoteService remoteService;
   private final MySecondService secondService;
}
```

**Step 3**  : Unit test, you can use mocking frameworks like Mockito to mock the RemoteService and MySecondService.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class MyServiceTest {

@Mock
private RemoteService remoteService;

@Mock
private MySecondService secondService;

private MyService myService;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    myService = new MyService(remoteService, secondService);
}

// ... Your test methods
```

}

Comment: Thanks! This was my solution. I've written it as an answer. :D

Answer (score 4):

Just do dependency injection like you normally would and move the `RemoteServiceFactory.newInstance()` to an `@Bean` annotated method. Problem solved.

```java
@Bean
public RemoveService remoteService() {
  return RemoteServiceFactory.newInstance()
}
```

```java
@Service
public class MyService {
   private final RemoteService remoteService;
   private final MySecondService secondService;

  public MyService(RemoteService remoteService, MySecondService secondService) {
    this.remoteService = remoteService;
    this.secondService = secondService;
  }
  // Remainder of methods
}
```

**NOTE:** I removed the use of Lombok here due to personal preference not to use it, you can ofcourse use the `@RequiredArgsConstructor` if you prefer.

Comment: Thank you. This is the solution I was looking for.

Comment: that is the proper way to use dependecy injection (+1), see [why field injection is evil](https://odrotbohm.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for previous answers.

I've ended up with a configuration which generates bean definition of RemoteService from thrid-party lib.

```java
@Configuration
public RemoteServiceConfig {
    @Bean
    public RemoteService remoteService() {
        return RemoteServiceFactory.newInstance();
    }
}
```

Not I can be autowired.